# print formated Invoice in c# application

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, printing

I have a `BillForm` in C# application in which I make entries of product now i want to Print this in a proper Receipt format (where company details will come from DB).I have searched about it and got many options like pdf print , report print ,vs power packs.I'm confused now as looking for easy and right option.
In my mind i want to do something like

```
    //in BillForm
PrintButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // now a formated form should be open ReceiptForm
 // values should be shifted from BillForm to ReceiptForm dynamically 
}
```

Correct me if my idea is not correct as I'm doing it for first time.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks **[I'm not asking for code,Sugeest me as headings or points]**

Comment: The downvotes (not mine) probably are for the lack of research. Lock at those 'Related' posts at the right side of this Page for further reading!! ---->>>

Comment: @TaW thanks for time .I have seen the related posts before posting the question and i'm only asking the better way because i'm confused as foundso many different answers

Comment: Well, we can't decide how to do it for you or sift through the various posts. You need to start and come back with concrete questions about the code you have!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a good looking (i.e. professional) receipt/invoice etc you should finally produce a PDF file.

Use some PDF library and build the document form the data/structure/contents you already have.

Or use a two step approach:

Render your text in a RTF (Rich Text Format) control. 
Then use the control's ConvertToPdf method.

Both methods require to research for a) the best suited PDF library and b) the best suited RTF control.

I'd avoid any 'Reporting' or 'Report-Generating' library, because this is overkill (too much, too complicated) for your requirements.